# Reduce method - cannot get two seperate results

Tags: javascript

I've got an array like that:

```
   const arr = [
    [{rivals: ['player1','player2'], winner: "player1", player1Scored: 2, player2Scored: 1}],
    [{rivals: ['player1','player3'], winner: "none", player1Scored: 2, player3Scored: 2}],
    [{rivals: ['player2','player3'], winner: "player3", player2Scored: 1, player3Scored: 3}],
    [{rivals: ['player1','player4'], winner: "none", player1Scored: 1, player4Scored: 1}]
    ]
```

I need to count scored points of every player, so it'll look like that:

```
{player1Scored: 5, player2Scored: 2, player3Scored: 5, player4Scored:1}
```

I tried this:

```
let scoreResult = arr.reduce((result, {0: obj}) => {
    obj.rivals.forEach(rival => result[`${rival}Scored`] = result[`${rival}Scored`] || 0);

    obj.rivals.forEach(rival => result[`${rival}Scored`] += obj.player1Scored)

    return result;
}, {});
```

My mistake is that I'm asigning points of one player to two of them but cannot solve that.

Thank you for your help

Comment: does it have a special reason, why the objects are nested in an array with a single element?

Comment: You're using `obj.player1Scored` even when player 1 wasn't one of the rivals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the problem, you have nested arrays with a single object. You could take a destructuring with the array and take the firts item as object.

Then take the names from `rivals` array and add the scores.

```js
const
    array = [[{ rivals: ['player1', 'player2'], winner: "player1", player1Scored: 2, player2Scored: 1 }], [{ rivals: ['player1', 'player3'], winner: "none", player1Scored: 2, player3Scored: 2 }], [{ rivals: ['player2', 'player3'], winner: "player3", player2Scored: 1, player3Scored: 3 }], [{ rivals: ['player1', 'player4'], winner: "none", player1Scored: 1, player4Scored: 1 }]],
    result = array.reduce((r, [o]) => {
        o.rivals.forEach(k => r[k + 'Scored'] = (r[k + 'Scored'] || 0) + o[k + 'Scored']);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
scores = {}
arr.map(s => s[0]).forEach(s => {
    s.rivals.forEach(r => {
        scores[r] = scores[r] || 0;
        scores[r] += s[`${r}Scored`]
    })
})
```